# encountering errors when I try to run angular.io "tour of heroes" final plunk

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-tour-of-heroes

I downloaded the final plunk for angular.io "tour of heroes" but I'm encountering errors. I'm using the package.json file from the first plunk because a package.json file isn't provided in the final plunk.  npm start returns the errors below.  This is a fresh install of everything as of tonight.  I googled some of these errors and saw a few suggestions which I tried but the errors persist.  Any idea how to fix?

```
app/app.component.ts(4,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
app/dashboard.component.ts(8,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
app/hero-detail.component.ts(9,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
app/hero-search.component.ts(10,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
app/heroes.component.ts(8,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(21,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(85,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'name' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(145,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.unscopables]' must be of type '{ copyWithin: boolean; entries: boolean; fill: boolean; find: boolean; findIndex: boolean; keys: ...', but here has type 'any'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(262,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'flags' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(276,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'EPSILON' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(311,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(318,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(457,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must be of type '"Symbol"', but here has type 'string'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(457,5): error TS2687: All declarations of '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(464,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(492,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'hasInstance' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(498,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'isConcatSpreadable' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(504,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'iterator' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(510,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'match' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(516,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'replace' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(522,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'search' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(528,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'species' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(534,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'split' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(540,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'toPrimitive' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(546,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'toStringTag' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(552,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'unscopables' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(609,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must be of type '"Math"', but here has type 'string'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(609,5): error TS2687: All declarations of '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(613,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must be of type '"JSON"', but here has type 'string'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(613,5): error TS2687: All declarations of '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(628,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'size' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(634,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(645,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'size' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(651,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(666,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(680,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(692,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'value' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(804,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(4133,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json` you need to add

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
]
```

so it won't try to compile node_modules and typings folders.

Comment: @iJungleBoy Can you give more details on what didn't work and what the error is?

Comment: I'll have to look into it again. from what I remember it's a bit of a back-and-forth, I believe it was something like "if you try AoT, it fails, find solution in stack-overflow. apply that, then you get all the errors in the non AoT" or something. but I won't be able to look at it for another week or so. thx for the quick reply

Comment: Hmm I am not sure, have to see the entire log, let me know I guess :) and np!

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove @types/core-js by running the following command:
   **"npm uninstall @types/core-js"**
2. Then install core-js by running the following command:
   **"npm install core-js --save"**

Answer (score 0):

Remove %localappdata%\Microsoft\Typescript, then run: npm install -g typescript@2.1